# Use shared_ptr with preallocated pointer

Tags: c++, std, shared-ptr

Is it problematic to assign a preallocated pointer to a shared_ptr object ?
For example:

```
some_type* 3rd_party_func(...)  
{  
  return new some_pointer;  
}  

re_val my_func()  
{  
shared_ptr<some_type> my_ptr(3rd_party_func());  
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You'll most probably need a custom deleter function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not a problem at all.  It's quite common actually.  As a bonus, if your third-party library returns a pointer which is supposed to be deallocated using a library function rather than `delete`, you can do this:

```
shared_ptr<some_type> my_ptr(3rd_party_func(), 3rd_party_free);
```